# find select option with selected property using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a view that loads `select` elements dynamically into the page on certain button clicks. Each of these `select`s have the same id value followed with an index value based on how many times the button is clicked. so the id would be like

```
id="my_id_" + numOfClicks;
```

I have also given all these selectors the same class value

```
class="selects"
```

What is the best way to have an event handler for when the selected option changes in any of the drop downs. right now I have the following:

```
$('.selects').change(function() {
    if($('this option:selected').val() == 0) {

    }
    else {

    }
});
```

So what I'm trying to do is first get the right select element using "this" then figure out which of the options are selected. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can use `$(this).val()`

Comment: However you also can use your method if you put the context right `if($('option:selected',this)`

Comment: Or you can use like *this.value*

Comment: @Regent `this.value`.

Comment: looks like a few options are available, let me try a couple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming html input.selects:

```
$('body').on('change', '.selects', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '0') {

    }
    else {

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4pxx0yy/1/

No quote around this.

Comment: Use `this.value`, not `$(this).val()`.

Comment: I would be inclined to use `$("body").on('change', '.selects', function() {` ... this will handle dynamically added elements more efficiently.

Comment: @james-donnelly, this.value is preferred, but the jQuery abstraction seems to help a lot of newer programmers. Also, there's likely more jQuery on the DOM Object.  It makes the code easier to read when you have

var $this = $(this)

and then stick to jQuery conventions, then you don't have to keep looking up which methods work and don't work on vanilla and jQuery objects. Perfectly fine when you just need something to work and it's a small one off.

But ultimately, I agree, it's easier not to use jQuery once you know how.  But this is a jQuery tag. 

Edit: fixed name and added note about tag.

Comment: i thought this.value gets the value that was assigned when the view first loads, and doesn't update if the selection is changed? or is this not true? I know with text type inputs when I try to use .value rather than .val(), if the input text changes since page load, the .value doesn't seem to reflect that

Comment: @rfornal - Definitely, but I wanted to limit scope of my answer.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad `this.value` works normally even in IE8: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr2Lyzwh/) (while jsfiddle.net does not, but whatever).

Comment: @AbdulAhmad it should work. I made a fiddle, maybe I missed something? (likely) http://jsfiddle.net/r4pxx0yy/

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: You're thinking of the `value` **attribute** on `input` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/u2p29njr/ The `value` *property* reflects the current value of the `input` (or `select`), but (on `input`s) the `value` *attribute* doesn't change (and is available via the `defaultValue` reflected property).

Answer (score 2):

As you say these get added at runtime, you'll want a delegated event handler. Within the handler, as the comments have pointed out, it's just `$(this).val()` to get the selected value of that `select` box. So:

```
$("selector for some container they're in").on("change", ".selects", function() {
    if($(this).val() == 0) {

    }
    else {

    }
});
```

For instance, if they're all inside an element with the class `container`, then:

```
$(".container").on("change", ".selects", function() {
    if($(this).val() == 0) {

    }
    else {

    }
});
```

If there's no other suitable container, you can just use `$(document).on(...`, but usually it's better to handle things a bit closer to where they are than that.

---

Side note: Values are always strings, but `==` will coerce, so `"0" == 0` is true. Still, it's useful to remember that they're strings.